# Using PDFs to calculate optimally weighted average

Tags: expected-value, beta-distribution

I want to calculate the expected value of a parent node in a search tree, where the parent node has three children A, B, C. The goal is that the expected value of the parent should reflect the probable outcome if the best branch in the tree is followed, so the higher the value of a node, the higher weight it should have.

The beta distribution describes the PDF for A, B, C, and I would like to calculate the average of them based on their PDFs, but I'm not sure how to do that analytically. I understand that I could sample numbers from A, B and C using the besta distribution and then the proportion of wins for each child would be a good estimate of the weight I want to assign to them when calculating the expected value of the parent, but I suspect that an analytical solution could be faster.

To be more concrete, consider the following parameters for the child nodes

Child node A: alpha = 2, beta = 13.4 (mean = 0.13)

Child node B: alpha = 2, beta = 8 (mean = 0.2)

Child node C: alpha = 2, beta = 5.78 (mean = 0.26)

```
alpha <- c(2, 2, 2)
beta <- c(13.4, 8, 5.72)

curve(dbeta(x, alpha[1], beta[1]), col = "red", ylab = "", xlab = "", lwd = 2)
curve(dbeta(x, alpha[2], beta[2]), col = "blue", add = TRUE, lwd = 2)
curve(dbeta(x, alpha[3], beta[3]), col = "green", add = TRUE, lwd = 2)
```

[image: PDFs for node A, B and C]

Now, I can achieve what I think is the right answer with sampling, e.g.

```
my.sampling.f <- function() {
    this.sample <- c(rbeta(n=1, shape1=alpha[1], shape2=beta[1]),
                     rbeta(n=1, shape1=alpha[2], shape2=beta[2]),
                     rbeta(n=1, shape1=alpha[3], shape2=beta[3]))
    LETTERS[which(this.sample == max(this.sample))] ## return multiple winners if tie
}

(expected.weights <- prop.table(table(replicate(n=1E5, my.sampling.f()))))
     A      B      C 
0.1166 0.3278 0.5556 
(expected.average <- sum(expected.weights * c(alpha[1]/(alpha[1] + beta[1]), alpha[2]/(alpha[2] + beta[2]), alpha[3]/(alpha[3] + beta[3]))))
[1] 0.2246407
```

But my application is time critical, so I very much need something faster than sampling, and perhaps there is an analytical solution?

Comment: How did you obtain the mean for each node?, seems wrong. And after that, what is the meaning of the result in expected.average?

Comment: Oh, thanks for pointing that out, I initially forgot to substract one from alpha and beta when I derived them, I have updated the question now. The means are calculated as (alpha[1]-1)/(beta[1]-1).

The meaning of the expected.average is what I believe is the optimally weighted average which I would like to get through some faster procedure than sampling.

Comment: Mean of beta is alfa/(alfa+beta). The value of expected weights seem to be the proportion of times each node gives the biggest value. Do you want to know the node more likely to give the highest value?

Comment: I see, my knowledge about the beta distribution is very vague, so the means are not correct, I have update them again, thanks your input.

"The value of expected weights seem to be the proportion of times each node gives the biggest value." That is exactly what I intended to use as a weight for the average for the parent, so far so good.

"Do you want to know the node more likely to give the highest value?" No.

Comment: Then , what do you want as a value for the parent? The expected value of a randomly chosen beta?

Comment: A randomly chosen node, you mean? Yeah, as long as the randomization follows the principle I showed with the sampling: the samples from each node is drawn using the beta distribution that describes the expected outcome for each node.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108071/discussion-between-hans-ekbrand-and-javierazcoiti).